# What branches of mathematics study line intersections, distance between planes and points, et cetera?

Tags: calculus

Consider these problems.

1. Find the point at which the line intersects the a given plane.
2. Find the angle between two planes.
3. Find the line of intersection of two planes.
4. What's the distance between this plane and this point.
5. Prove that two lines are neither parallel nor do they intersect.
6. Find an equation for the surface consisting of all points equidistant from some specific point and some specific plane.

What's the branch of mathematics that wishes for answers to these problems?

Comment: differential-geometry ?

Comment: I would say linear algebra, in combination with geometry, and perhaps some trigonometry.

Comment: [Analytic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_geometry).

Comment: This is covered as background in multivariable calculus, though admittedly it is not exactly calculus it's just the first time most of the students at my school actually see it :)

Comment: These are very low-level questions, so you can go in many different directions. How many intersections in a generic case? Algebraic geometry. Properties of hyperplane arrangements? Combinatorics or representation theory. And so on.

Comment: It's analytic geometry, people.

Comment: Without 6, Euclidean geometry would do. But 6 asks for an equation, which moves it strictly into analytic geometry. Of course, every subject that builds off of analytic geometry, such as linear algebra and calculus and even differential geometry, also works.